# trying to get my while loop to use value that fits criteria and not the first input that was given java

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

### so I'm trying to figure out why my while loop takes the first value that is given and uses that for my equation even if it doesnt fit the criteria (it being greater than 250)

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

double cost;
double costWithTax;
double costWithSurcharge;
double payment;
double changeDue;
double costWithTaxAndSurcharge;

//equations
costWithTax = (cost * taxRate) + cost;
surcharge = cost * surcharge;
costWithTaxAndSurcharge = costWithTax + surcharge;

if (cost < 10)
{
        cost = surcharge + costWithTax;
    System.out.printf("Amount due: $%.2f ", cost);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.printf("Surcharge added is: $%.2f ", surcharge);
}
else if (cost <= 250)
{
    cost = costWithTax;
    System.out.printf("Amount due: $%.2f ", cost);
}
while (cost > 250)
{
    System.out.print("Enter transaction amount: ");
    cost = kb.nextDouble();
    cost++;

        cost  = costWithTax;
    System.out.printf("Amount due: $%.2f ", cost);
    break;  
}
```

Comment: What is the `first value that is given`?

Comment: Can you post what Is the value of ```cost```?

Comment: cost is just a double and it's based on the users input

Comment: @Mark System.out.print("Enter transaction amount: ");
  cost = kb.nextDouble();

Comment: @ThumChoonTat System.out.print("Enter transaction amount: ");
  cost = kb.nextDouble();

Comment: @CorinneBond so you have those if/elseif statements using ```cost``` that the user will input in the while loop?

Comment: @mark yes. Do you want to see the entire code to better understand?

Comment: @CorinneBond Just kindly edit the post to include the initial values of the ```cost```, ```surcharge``` and ```costWithTax```

Comment: @mark just updated it,

Comment: @CorinneBond can you describe what your code will do? Also you are not initializing all those variables before using them

Comment: @mark my code is supposed to act a “cash register” and based on the users input which is “cost”. If the cost is below $10 their is a surcharge of 10% added along with 7% tax. But if the input is greater than $250, it is supposed to prompt the user to enter an amount & keep repeating until the value is less than or equal to $250. After a value less than 250 is entered the code should carry on out using the first input that’s given by the user that meets the criteria, instead of just the first value given

Comment: @CorinneBond Okay, now I understand, I will post an answer soon

Answer (score 0):

Your process is a mess. I have revised the code and included comments. Refer to the code below.

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

double cost;
double costWithTax;
double costWithSurcharge;
double payment = 0; // initialized payment
double changeDue;
double costWithTaxAndSurcharge;
double taxRate = 0.07; // 7% tax
double surcharge = 0.10; // 10% surcharge

System.out.print("Enter transaction amount: "); // get the cost first before doing the equations
cost = kb.nextDouble();

while (cost > 250) { // check if the cost is greater than 250, since if greater than 250 it is an invalid cost (from your explanation)
    System.out.print("Input greater than $250. Pleas enter transaction amount again: ");
    cost = kb.nextDouble(); // get the cost again
}

// equations
costWithTax = (cost * taxRate) + cost; // get the cost with the tax added to it
costWithSurcharge = cost * surcharge; // change to costWithSurcharge from surcharge, so that the value of surcharge will not be overwritten, this will be the cost with surcharge
costWithTaxAndSurcharge = costWithTax + costWithSurcharge; // (#1) get the new cost, cost with tax and surcharge 

if (cost < 10) {
    cost = costWithTaxAndSurcharge; // just assign costWithTaxAndSurcharge to cost, no need to calculate again, same calculations with (#1) above
    System.out.printf("Amount due: $%.2f ", cost);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.printf("Surcharge added is: $%.2f ", surcharge);
} else if (cost <= 250) {
    cost = costWithTax;
    System.out.printf("Amount due: $%.2f ", cost);
}

System.out.print("Enter payment amount: ");
payment = kb.nextDouble();

while (payment <= cost) {
    System.out.print("Payment is invalid. Enter payment amount agian: ");
    payment = kb.nextDouble();
}

changeDue = payment - cost;
System.out.print("Change due: " + changeDue);

kb.close();
```